# JQGrid How do I removed the annoying horizontal scrollbar when autowidth = true? (In IE)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I seem to be getting an annoying horizontal scrollbar when using autowidth=true in IE

What is going on here and how do I get rid of it?

[image: Annoying horizontal scrollbar]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make your grid tall enough to contain all the rows. The horizontal scrollbar is there because the vertical scrollbar is taking up some of the width normally used by the rows.

Answer (score 9):

I got perfect Solution. The problem is in CSS. In ui-jqgrid.css the table layout is in Fixed. Make it as auto it will work perfectly. I just copied the same class i.e.,

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-btable
{
  table-layout:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the scrollOffset option to something like 20 - 30, this will fix the horizontal scrollbar adjustment problem.

Answer (score 1):

Set the scrollOffset to 18 - it's solve the problem.
Quick and effective.

Thanks, Corey Schomer!

Answer (score 0):

setting table-layout: auto could be slow. if you have lots of data

this is from w3school (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp)

Automatic table layout algorithm (this is default):
The column width is set by the widest unbreakable content in the cells
Can be slow, since it needs to read through all the content in the table, before determining the final layout